# Reversibility and stationary probability

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, self-learning, markov-chains

> Let $X_n$ a markov chain with transition matrix given by
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}0.7&0.3&0\\0.2&0.7&0.1\\0.4&0.1&0.5\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> i) Find the stationary probability
>
> ii)Starting from state "2", which is the expected number of steps that
>   the process must do to return to the same state?
>
> iii)This Markov Chain is reversible?

What I did

i)$$\pi P=\pi$$
$$0.7\pi_0+0.2\pi_1+0.4\pi_2=\pi_0$$
$$0.3\pi_0+0.7\pi_1+0.1\pi_2=\pi_1$$
$$\pi_0+\pi_1+\pi_2=1$$
solving this I get
$$\begin{bmatrix}\pi_0 &\pi_1 &\pi_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0.09375& 0.4685 &0.4375\end{bmatrix}$$

ii)Let $T$ be the number of steps required to get back to 2 when start in 2, then
$$E[T]=\frac{1}{\pi_2}=\frac{1}{0.4375}\approx 2.28$$

iii)How do I check that the chain is reversible? I need to check this
$$\pi(x)P(x,y)=\pi(y)P(y,x)\forall x,y$$

EDIT: Following a tip from @John it is easy to see that this chain is not reversible, but supposing that $$P(x,y)>0\forall x,y$$
It would be very laborious check many cases to find one that is not valid.

Is there any other criteria to check reversibility?

EDIT: Check the balance condition and reversibility is the same thing?

Comment: Hint: Is $P(0,2)=0$ but $P(2,0)>0$ consistent with reversibility?

Comment: @JohnDawkins But if $P(x,y)>0\forall x,y$ then you would need to check all the possibilities?

Comment: @Roland My prof usually just check one case and gives his verdict. Not sure if that is 100% reliable tho.